# C# underscore as argument to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, arguments

I have the following C# code which I want to convert to VB.NET:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using OpenCvSharp;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sPath = "c:\\users\\myuser\\desktop\\lenna.png";

            using (var src = new Mat(sPath, ImreadModes.Color))
            using (var srcGray = new Mat(sPath, ImreadModes.GrayScale))
            using (var hsv = new Mat())
            using (var dst = new Mat())
            {
                Cv2.CvtColor(src, hsv, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2HSV);
                Cv2.CvtColor(srcGray, dst, ColorConversionCodes.GRAY2BGR);

                var hsvChannels = Cv2.Split(hsv);
                var v = hsvChannels[2];

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    using (var bin = new Mat())
                    {
                        Cv2.Threshold(v, bin, i * 32, 255, ThresholdTypes.Tozero);
                        Cv2.Threshold(bin, bin, (i + 1) * 32, 255, ThresholdTypes.BinaryInv);

                        Cv2.FindContours(bin, out var contours, out _, RetrievalModes.External,
                            ContourApproximationModes.ApproxNone);
                        Cv2.DrawContours(dst, contours, -1, Scalar.Red, 1);
                    }
                }

                Window.ShowImages(dst);

                foreach (var m in hsvChannels)
                    m.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I managed to convert it, but the "_" gives me a headache.

The compiler tells me "Not the most specific" if I replace it with "Nothing".

And if I declare "contours" like that (to be more specific), the compiler tells me that "Nothing" is an invalid argument:

```
Dim contours As OpenCvSharp.Mat()
```

Here is my VB.NET attempt:

```
Imports OpenCvSharp

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim sPath As String = "c:\users\myuser\desktop\lenna.png"

        Using src = New Mat(sPath, ImreadModes.Color)
            Using srcGray = New Mat(sPath, ImreadModes.GrayScale)
                Using hsv = New OpenCvSharp.Mat()
                    Using dst = New Mat()
                        Cv2.CvtColor(src, hsv, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2HSV)
                        Cv2.CvtColor(srcGray, dst, ColorConversionCodes.GRAY2BGR)

                        Dim hsvChannels = Cv2.Split(hsv)
                        Dim v = hsvChannels(2)

                        For i As Integer = 0 To 7
                            Using bin = New Mat()
                                Cv2.Threshold(v, bin, i * 32, 255, ThresholdTypes.Tozero)
                                Cv2.Threshold(bin, bin, (i + 1) * 32, 255, ThresholdTypes.BinaryInv)

                                Dim contours
                                Cv2.FindContours(bin, contours, Nothing, RetrievalModes.External, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxNone) // Compiler error occurs here
                                Cv2.DrawContours(dst, contours, -1, Scalar.Red, 1)
                            End Using
                        Next i

                        Window.ShowImages(dst)

                        For Each m In hsvChannels
                            m.Dispose()
                        Next m
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm not sure what the compiler wants from me. Does anybody know? 
Using an underscore or double underscore (as some online converters suggested) won't work.

These are the declarations of FindContours:

```
Public Shared Sub FindContours(image As InputOutputArray, ByRef contours() As Mat, hierarchy As OutputArray, mode As RetrievalModes, method As ContourApproximationModes, Optional offset As Point? = Nothing)

Public Shared Sub FindContours(image As InputOutputArray, ByRef contours As Point()(), ByRef hierarchy() As HierarchyIndex, mode As RetrievalModes, method As ContourApproximationModes, Optional offset As Point? = Nothing)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An underscore argument in C# is a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards). VB has no equivalent of this, as far as I know. Since this is an `out` parameter, you need to declare a local dummy variable and pass that:

```
Dim contours As Point()()
Dim unused As HierarchyIndex()
Cv2.FindContours(bin, contours, unused, RetrievalModes.External, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxNone)
```

Also note that your local declaration of `contours` lacks a type and is thus incomplete. The compiler should reject this as invalid (if you’re compiling with `Option Strict`, which you should).

Comment: I have now done it as you suggested, and additionally declared "Dim contours() As OpenCvSharp.Mat", however, the compiler tells me "NullException: The Parametername hierarchy may not be NULL".

Comment: @tmighty Thanks, I declared it with the wrong type. I fixed it, it should work now.

Comment: The compiler tells me that there's no overloads for these arguments.

Comment: @tmighty Ugh, try again. I messed up once more. That said, the declaration you posted is a bit weird since the parameter isn’t declared as `ByRef` (`out` in C#) so this shouldn’t work — or at least it’s not equivalent to the C# code.

Comment: Now it tells me "Error overloading since New isn't available". I also tried "Dim unused = New OpenCvSharp.OutputArray()", but that gives the same result.

Comment: @tmighty OK, try the other overload (`contours As Point()()` and `unused as HierarchyIndex()`). We’ll get there! Unfortunately I don’t have a VB compiler at hand to check the syntax of the declarations but it should work.

Comment: That did it!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not know what overload you want to use, because you did not give a type to `contours`. Specify what Type `contours` is, either `Dim contours as Point()` or `Dim contours as Mat`.

An underscore `_` is used in csharp when you're not interested in the parameter value. Because VB does not have a out mechanism, you have to specify a temporary variable for the underscore argument `Dim hierarchy() As HierarchyIndex` or `Dim hierarchy As OutputArray`.

When using VB.net make sure you specify parameter types - and if possible enable strict type checking. This forces you to write cleaner code that is more type safe. This will save you a lot of headaches.